# php - access folder on another site on the same server

Tags: php

I have a dedicated server running centos, I have serval sites on this server and all of them are mine.
I want use php to upload files -videos- where the file exit on the other site.

let me explain
/home/user1/public_html/uploads => the videos are here => domain.com

/home/user2/public_html/upload.php => the php file to upload on another site on the same server => domain.net

how can I let the other site upload a video from my other website that on the same server.

I wish that was clear

Comment: Could be as simple as `move_uploaded_file($source, `/home/user1/public_html/uploads`.$targetname);`

Comment: Addendum to the comment above: after making sure permissions are correctly set